Identifying Talk Back usage on non-Google and non-Samsung devices
We are using OS accessibility service APIs to track the number of screen reader users we have on both iOS and Android. But we are seeing some smelly results and this had made me wonder if our implementation needs adjusting. Our Android user base is on Google and Samsung devices at a rate of 75%. However, when we measure the number of Talk Back users within our overall Android user base, only 30% are reporting in our analytics system as being on Google and Samsung devices. In particular, Motorola is overrepresented for Talk Back unique users being reported. In general, as an org we are seeing more Android Talk Back users than we are iOS Voice Over users, which we're certain is nigh impossible given our overall user base strongly favoring iOS and general trends within the accessibility community. (Screen reader users strongly favor iOS/ VoiceOver.)
I am aware that Google and Samsung use different package names for Talk Back:

Google: com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService
Samsung: com.samsung.android.accessibility.talkback/com.samsung.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService

As such we have avoided using specific package names to ID screen reader users. Is it possible that other manufacturers might be over-reporting Talk Back users/ screen views because "talkback" as an identifier might include users who are not strictly speaking using a screen reader? And are there any better recommended approaches for gathering this kind of data on Android?
See snippet for example of how we are gathering this data on Android.
class MyUseCase(
    context: Context,
) {
    private val accessibilityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager?

    operator fun invoke(): Map<String, String> {
        val enabledFeatures = getAllAccessibilityServicesEnabled().joinToString(separator = "|")
        return mapOf(ACCESSIBILITY_KEY to enabledFeatures)
    }

    private fun getAllAccessibilityServicesEnabled(): List<String> {
        val accessibilityServiceInfoList =
            accessibilityManager?.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(
                AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK,
            )
        return accessibilityServiceInfoList?.map {
            when {
                it.id.contains(TALK_BACK) -> "Talk Back"
                it.id.contains(SWITCH_ACCESS) -> "Switch Access"
                it.id.contains(UNIVERSAL_SWITCH) -> "Universal Switch"
                it.id.contains(VOICE_ACCESS) -> "Voice Access"
                it.id.contains(SELECT_TO_SPEAK) -> "Select to Speak"
                it.id.contains(BRAILLE_BACK) -> "Braille Back"
                else -> "Unknown"
            }
        } ?: emptyList()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ACCESSIBILITY_KEY = "accessibility"
        private const val TALK_BACK = "talkback"
        private const val SWITCH_ACCESS = "switchaccess"
        private const val UNIVERSAL_SWITCH = "universalswitch"
        private const val VOICE_ACCESS = "voiceaccess"
        private const val SELECT_TO_SPEAK = "selecttospeak"
        private const val BRAILLE_BACK = "brailleback"
    }
}


Have you checked my solution yet?

Yes, It's possible that various companies could exchange information regarding the number of Talkback users or screen views given that "(talkback)" serves as the package name, for the screen reader utilized on Android devices. This designation may vary across manufacturers such, as Pixel, Honor, Huawei and Samsung.
TL;DR

Part 1
To obtain the precise data of usage of accessibility on android apps it is necessary for advanced and more reliable methods to be utilized. Here are some recommended approaches:Here are some recommended approaches:
Accessibility Event Tracking:
The AccessibilityEvent APIs is just one of such that they are exposed to an Android user through this monitoring screen reader usage, focus changes, and interactions. You have the incredible possibility to find out how many people have been using accessibility services of these types of events.
Custom Analytics Events:
Build in a track of analytics clicks specific to accessibility functionalities within your application. The same example illustrates the fact of event tracking. This can be useful while tracking when users enable or disable accessibility services; interact with accessible elements, or navigate through accessible content. Thus, it delivers a high-quality data with pin point accuracy that you can personalize and customize with respect to the purpose you are using it for.
User Surveys and Feedback:
Integrate such mechanisms of feedback and surveys into your application by gathering the first-hand information directly from users. Asking questions that are targeting accessibility usage is indispensable.  You can get to know if they use screen readers, magnification gestures, and other accessibility features or not. In this fashion, data acquired from different contexts is being verified and one obtains qualitative knowledge on user experience.
Integration with Accessibility Services:
Collaborate with other organizations that run the service of accessibility and service providers to gathering the anonymized adoption data directly by their services. This method requires partnerships and agreements but it also enables to the readers accessibility usage engagement accessing to the broader users.
Contextual Analysis:
Explore user analysis and behaviour's; later on go through the patterns of usage of the app to estimate an indirect use of accessibility. For instance, a pattern that many people follow might be including those people that often adjust font sizes or use mode to high contrast or navigate through using keyboard shortcuts.  These people may be attempting to reveal their accessibility needs.
Different OS Compatibility:
Implement the necessary data collection measures for compatibility with different version of Android, device manufacturers as well as service configurations of accessibility. This in turn ensures that information is presented well and shops the gap of irregularities in the user environment.

Part 2
You may optimise code this way :
object AccessibilityUtils {

    private const val TALK_BACK = "talkback"
    private const val SWITCH_ACCESS = "switchaccess"
    private const val UNIVERSAL_SWITCH = "universalswitch"
    private const val VOICE_ACCESS = "voiceaccess"
    private const val SELECT_TO_SPEAK = "selecttospeak"
    private const val BRAILLE_BACK = "brailleback"

    // Retrieve information about enabled accessibility services and return a map with service names
    fun getEnabledAccessibilityServices(context: Context): Map<String, String> {
        val accessibilityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager?
        val enabledServices = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

        val enabledServicesList = accessibilityManager?.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK)

        enabledServicesList?.forEach { serviceInfo ->
            val serviceId = serviceInfo.id.toString()
            enabledServices[getServiceName(serviceId)] = serviceInfo.resolveInfo?.serviceInfo?.name ?: ""
        }

        return enabledServices.toMap() // Create an immutable map
    }

    private fun getServiceName(serviceId: String): String {
        return when {
            serviceId.contains(TALK_BACK) -> "Talk Back"
            serviceId.contains(SWITCH_ACCESS) -> "Switch Access"
            serviceId.contains(UNIVERSAL_SWITCH) -> "Universal Switch"
            serviceId.contains(VOICE_ACCESS) -> "Voice Access"
            serviceId.contains(SELECT_TO_SPEAK) -> "Select to Speak"
            serviceId.contains(BRAILLE_BACK) -> "Braille Back"
            else -> "Unknown"
        }
    }
}

Usage :
val accessibilityMap = AccessibilityUtils.getEnabledAccessibilityServices(context)
val isTalkBackEnabled = accessibilityMap.containsKey("Talk Back")

Accessibility

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent
https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service#ListenForEvents
https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006564

Design

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service
https://material.io/design/usability/accessibility.html

